# how to make ruby on rails application all mobiles compatible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, jqtouch

i want to make my test app running on rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3 mobile compatable so that it can work on every mobile+ on desktop as well.so do i need to check/include every user agent such iphone/webos etc or is there any other way....OR just make my app compatible with mobile using jqtouch and everything will work fine irrespective of mobile device??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your personal choice:

1. use a css framework such as zurb,bootstrap and smartly use their classes such as `col-lg-12(for desktops),col-md-12(for ipads),col-sm-12(for small devices) and col-xs-12(for xtra small devices)` to make your web app desktop/mobile/ipad compatible
2. Or You can use [jqtouch](http://jqtouch.com/) mentioned in ryan bates railscasts [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/199-mobile-devices) to detect if a call is coming from a mobile using user-agent and then show mobile pages or else your default html.erb pages.But here you need to include a mobile page for every desktop for example : index.html.erb(for desktop) and index.mobile.erb(for mobile)

its your choice.